# Azure mobile services Custom API GET not returning XML instead Json

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

lately started looking into Azure mobile services and liked it. I usually prefer working with ASP.NET Web API but for a mobile solutions or any fast REST API development liked this approach. trying to figure out custom APIs, when I added a controller/custom API from on of my Web APIs code to the mobile project. it's working pretty good and simplified but when I see the response it's giving XML than Json response compared to other ToDo items API's.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using ProjectService.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ProjectService.Controllers
{
    public class ProjectController : ApiController
    {
        public ApiServices Services { get; set; }

        // GET api/Search
        public async Task<Movie> Get(string term)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

            var baseAddress = new Uri("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/");

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = baseAddress })
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "application/json");

                using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("search/movie?api_key=KEY-ID&query=" + term))

                {
                    string responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(responseData);

                    return model;

                    //I Tried with return Json AllowGet it's returning XML
                    //return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can control the response of the service by sending an `Accept: application/json` in the request that the client sends to it.

Comment: ya found it too. but I wonder when Todo item table APIs created for GET request without providing any header accept request, it responds with JSON string. I wonder why not with Custom APIs